# Struct of Pointers

Tags: c

I'm trying to store an array of structs with each struct having pointers but I get a "initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast" message in creating the array.

```
struct fl_valueags {
   tcflag_t *fl_value;
   flagtype_t *fl_type;
};
...
 struct fl_valueags t_flags[] = { { ttyinfo->c_iflag, INPUT }, {
     ttyinfo->c_oflag, OUTPUT }, { ttyinfo->c_cflag, CONTROL }, {
       ttyinfo->c_lflag, LOCAL } };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the address of `c_iflag`:

```
struct fl_valueags t_flags[] = {    { &ttyinfo->c_iflag, INPUT }, 
                                    { &ttyinfo->c_oflag, OUTPUT }, 
                                    { &ttyinfo->c_cflag, CONTROL }, 
                                    { &ttyinfo->c_lflag, LOCAL } };
```

Regarding the `fl_type`, it should probably be declared as a value, not a pointer (unless INPUT, OUTPUT CONTROL and LOCAL are pointers):

```
struct fl_valueags {
   tcflag_t *fl_value;
   flagtype_t fl_type;
};
```